# angular 2 checkbox to select all

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

## Problem

I looked for answers to this problem but I'm still stuck I have a table with multiple rows with a checkbox on every row, I need a checkbox to select all and deselect all, here some example code

**Template**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Diameter</th>
        <th class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="all" (change)="checkAll($event)"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let size of sizes | async ; let i = index">
        <td class="text-right">{{i + 1}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{size.size}}</td>
        <td>{{size.diameter}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Component**

```
    export class ListSizeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor () {
    }

    sizes: any;

    setSizes() {
        this.sizes = [
            {'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km'},
            {'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km'}
        ]
    }

    checkAll(ev) {
        if (ev.target.checked) {
            console.log("True")
        } else {
            console.log("False");
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setSizes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/K01n9vmSZyMi0VF5Nf1x?p=preview

Answer (score 19):

You can leverage `ngModel` to do that.

**Template**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)"/>
....
<input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}" [(ngModel)]="size.state"/>
```

**Component**:

```
checkAll(ev) {
  this.sizes.forEach(x => x.state = ev.target.checked)
}

isAllChecked() {
  return this.sizes.every(_ => _.state);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-29tq8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: I know this is an old answer now but I'm trying to do the same and I cannot get this to compile. Its complaining that state is not a property of size. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Plog Can you reproduce it in Plunker?

Comment: I'm just doing the same code as your Plunker example and it just doesn't know what 'state' is. Where does that come from??

Comment: @Plog I see. Try `sizes: any[]` or create special type. I also updated plunker

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry i'm very new to Angular and having trouble getting into it. So has something changed in Angular since you first answered this or what?

Answer (score 11):

This can be done **without** using **[(ngModel)]** also !

Just declare and initialize a boolean variable 'isSelected' to false in the component 'ListSizeComponent '.
And, add [Checked] = "isSelected" property to all the checkboxes. And, add the following change event of the 'all' checkbox.
(change)="isSelected = true".

So your code looks like below,

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Diameter</th>
        <th class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="all" (change)="isSelected = true"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let size of sizes | async ; let i = index">
        <td class="text-right">{{i + 1}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{size.size}}</td>
        <td>{{size.diameter}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}" 
             [checked]="isSelected"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

component:

```
export class ListSizeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor () {
}

sizes: any;
isSelected = false;

setSizes() {
    this.sizes = [
        {'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km'},
        {'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km'}
    ]
}



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setSizes();
}
```

Comment: `(change)="isSelected = !isSelected"` This will enable the checkbox to toggle. i.e. select all or unselect all.

Comment: yes. (change) = "isSelected = !isSelected" for toggle

Comment: What will happen if you need one of the checkboxes to come checked by default, but later uncheck it

Answer (score 6):

In HTML file:

Select all check box:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isSelected = !isSelected"> Select all
</div>
```

For List of checkboxes to be selected:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let feature of features">
 <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected"> {{feature.text}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code for doing select all checkbox.

```
<li> <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll();"/>
          </li>
          <li *ngFor="let n of names"> 
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="n.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected();">
          {{n.name}}
     </li>
```

.....

```
selectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
      this.names[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
    }
  }
  checkIfAllSelected() {
    this.selectedAll = this.names.every(function(item:any) {
        return item.selected == true;
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more modern approach without `ngModel` or external tracking of selected items. Pure `MatSelectionList` approach:

```
public toggle(list: MatSelectionList) {
    if (this.isAllChecked(list)) {
        list.deselectAll();
    } else {
        list.selectAll();
    }
}

public isAllChecked(list: MatSelectionList): boolean {
    // Make sure list exists
    if (!list.options)
        return false;
    return list.options.toArray().every(o => o.selected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is pretty simple (basically repeating Syed Muhammad Abid's answer).

TS:

```
multiSelect: boolean = true;
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" [checked]="multiSelect" (change)="multiSelect = !multiSelect"/></th>
        <th>Value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
       <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="multiSelect" /></td>
       <td>{{item.value}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What will happen if you select all elements in list? Common checkbox won't be checked

Answer (score 0):

```
zone1 = [
    { name: 'Capot avant', checked: false },
    { name: 'Pare-chocs avant', checked: false }
  ]

get selectedZone1() {enter code here
    return this.zone1.filter(item => item.checked).map(item => item.name)
  }


        <!-- zone 1 -->
  <ul>
    <h3 class="titre font-weight-bold zone"><b>ZONE 1</b></h3>
    <li *ngFor="let item of zone1">
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked">
        {{item.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide some info about what this code sample does.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work, I think it is because in my real code I get "sizes" by an async call to http.get trough a services and I got this error:

this.sizes.every is not a function

I mean sizes in the component is an Observable object

I have to correct my answer to clarify my situation, i have a service where I get the array sizes in this way:

```
getSizes () {

    let sizesUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/sizes';

    return this.http.get(sizesUrl).map(this.extractData)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    //console.log(body);
    let sizes: Size[] = new Array();
    for (let x = 0; x < body['hydra:member'].length; x++) {
        let size = new Size;
        let item = body['hydra:member'][x];
        size.id = item['@id'].substring(item['@id'].length - 1);
        size.size = item['size'];
        size.diameter = item['diameter'];
        size.example = item['example'];
        size.surfaceGravity = item['surfaceGravity'];
        sizes.push(size);
    }
    return sizes || { };
}
```

so in the component, sizes is an Observable, so if I call subscribe:

```
arr: any[];
sizes: any;

setSizes() {
    this.sizes = this.sizeService
        .getSizes()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.arr = data;
        });
}

checkAll(ev) {
    if(!this.arr) return;
    this.arr.forEach(x => x.state = ev.target.checked)
}

isAllChecked() {
    if(!this.arr) return;
    return this.arr.every(_ => _.state);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setSizes();
}
```

I got a compile error "Type '{}' is not assignable to type any[]", and sizes is not more an Observable object but it's a Subscriber object and I can't use it in the async pipe.
I'm sorry for all this confusion, I'm afraid that I was stuck in a tunnel with no way out.

thanks anyway for your answer :)

Comment: thank you, the problem was a wrong parameter in the subscribe in my code, damn I could not see it, thank you for your help :)